# como juntar um arquivo no html

Tags: html5

Eu gostaria de que quando o cliente clicasse no botão ver mais ele fosse a outra página do site...
ok, pra isso terei que criar outro documento html.
mas a minha dúvida é que se ainda é o código
a href="ver_mais.html no html5.

Comment: Especifica mais o que você está tentando fazer, posta o código html.

Comment: no `html5` não mudou nada em relação à navegação nos links, continua valendo *href*

Comment: Sim, a tag link ainda é a mesma! Seja bem vindo, faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**.

Comment: obg pela ajuda de voces